# saving object state in dealloc doesn't work

Tags: iphone, objective-c, release, dealloc

I noticed just now that when I save object state (`@public float`s converted to `NSString`s) in my dealloc method, using

```
+(void)savePreferences:(NSString*)key :(NSString*)value{
    NSMutableString* mutableString=[[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:value];
    CFPreferencesSetAppValue((CFStringRef)key, mutableString, kCFPreferencesCurrentApplication);    // Set up the preference.
    CFPreferencesAppSynchronize(kCFPreferencesCurrentApplication);// Write out the preference data.
    [mutableString release];
}
```

the wrong values are saved!?  If I instead save the values just before releasing, the correct values are saved. Note that I am careful to call `[super dealloc];` at the *end*.  Why is this?

Comment: Are you sure `-dealloc` is being called, hence `+savePreferences::` is being called as well?

Comment: Any particular reason you're not just using `NSUserDefaults`? (Since your posted code doesn't appear to be doing anything that `NSUserDefaults` couldn't already do (provided you're not assuming `-dealloc` will always be called).

Answer (score 2):

Several issues with that code;

- saving state in -dealloc is way too late.  By the time -dealloc is called, the object graph is in the midst of being torn down.
- on app termination, the system will not waste cycles tearing down your application.  It'll just inform it that it is about to be terminated and then terminate it;  if you are relying on -dealloc to be called, that might likely never happen.
- that method name isn't very good.  Try something like `savePreferencesValue:forKey:`.  However, the implication that it may be called many times would lead to a significant ineffeciency (in that it'd write the preferences plist over and over).
- the mutable string copy of the incoming value is a waste of cycles and memory;  no need for it
- unless you need the extended features of CFPreferences*() you should just stick with NSUserDefaults;  it will lead to less code and less fragility.

Comment: @bbum, @NSGod.  Thanks for comments, suggestions.  I tried replacing `savePreferences` with `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:key forKey:value];` and `loadPreferences` with `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:key];` but that didn't work!?--preferences were not saved--even when I synchronize. `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:key];` works when paired with my original `savePreferences` however.

Comment: @bbum. "the mutable string copy of the incoming value is a waste of cycles and memory; no need for it." True.  Don't know why I had that.  Thanks.

Comment: Given that NSUserDefaults *and* CFPreferences aren't working, I'd guess your problem is elsewhere;  specifically in how the data is derived in the first place.  Have you made sure you are passing the right values into the defaults persistence code in the first place?

Comment: @bbum, the problem with CFPreferences was that I was saving state in dealloc.  As long as I don't do that, my code works fine.  However I can't get NSUserDefaults to work (except for my loadPreferences, when paired with my original CFPreferences based savePrefrences function!?).  I _want_ to accept your answer, just need to clear this up!

Comment: It depends on which -dealloc.  If it is a dealloc that is occurring as parts of your app are being torn down (termination or the like), then the internal state of the frameworks may be undefined.  This is why doing *anything* in dealloc beyond basic resource reaping is a Very Bad Idea.  By definition, the object graph is in an indeterminate state;  you don't know what else may already have been partially or completely torn down or deallocated.

Comment: @bbum, OK, OK already.  I'm not doing anything in dealloc now.  Haven't been for a while.  Still CFPreferences works (to save data) while NSUserDefaults doesn't.  I can't accept your answer because you suggest using NSUserDefaults, which I haven't been able to get to work (to save data, outside of dealloc, to replace my CFPreferences which _does_ work).

Comment: OK;  no way to know how you modify your code if you don't post it. :)  In any case, are you calling -synchronize on NSUserDefaults?

Comment: @bbum, it might help if you read the comment at the top of this list :-(.